# Combining prepared statement and DISTINCT mysqli call

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use the prepared statement below:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT primaer FROM oevelser");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $primary);
    $stmt->execute();
```

When using DISTINCT, I'd expect to only get one result pr. row, thereby matching the number of variable types and variables nicely, but I get the error: "Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement"

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, meant to write: When naming a distinct column, I'd expect on result pr. row - DISTINCT has nothing to do with it, I guess...

Comment: You dont have any param in your query. Remove the `bind_param` and try again.

Comment: [**Prepared statements work like this...**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) - you're not using a placeholder which is what prepared statements are all about; ***that's why your code is failing.*** Do have a look in the manual and Google "mysqli prepared statements examples". This being just as good as an "answer".

Comment: @DerVO - You're completely right - don't know if there's a way to 'award' someone for a comment (in contrary to an answer...), but you nailed it - thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a parameter when your query doesn't specify one. A valid one would look something like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT primaer FROM oevelser WHERE primary=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $primary);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @ksealy, thanks for leading me on the right path - actually I needed to drop the bind_param, since my query doesn't need one.